# Spring Cloud Gateway with SAML

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-saml, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to use Spring Cloud Gateway with SAML. Is this possible? 
It seems that the Saml extension for spring security is based on the old Spring Stack and won't work with Gateway.

Has anybody got any experience on this?

Comment: Spring Security introduced SAML service provider support into the core module in version 5.2 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-saml2

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid SAML is not supported as of time of writing. **Spring Cloud Gateway** has been redeveloped using Reactive programming and is now based on Spring WebFlux. Only the following authentication methods are currently supported :

1. [OAuth 2.0 or OpenID Connect 1.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#webflux-oauth2-login)
2. [x509 authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#reactive-x509)

This is stated on [SCG page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/):

> Spring Cloud Gateway is built on Spring Boot 2.x, Spring WebFlux, and
> Project Reactor. As a consequence, many of the familiar synchronous
> libraries (Spring Data and Spring Security, for example) and patterns
> you know may not apply when you use Spring Cloud Gateway. If you are
> unfamiliar with these projects, we suggest you begin by reading their
> documentation to familiarize yourself with some of the new concepts
> before working with Spring Cloud Gateway.

The previous gateway `spring-cloud-netflix-zuul`, based on Servlets and which supported SAML, has been removed from [Spring Cloud 2020](https://spring.io/blog/2020/12/22/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-aka-ilford-is-available).

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7954) is an open issue on GitHub, **SAML2 for reactive environment**, where we can vote for asking for this to be implemented.